# invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c, algorithm

i want to make cashier program by C language. i using structure for record but the problem is when i try to display the receipt of payment by defined name of item `detail[i].name` and price `detail.[i].price` for looping, i got this message

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

this is my script

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    struct item{
        char name[10];
        int price;
        int barcode;
    };
    struct item detail[10]={
        "item1",10,1,
        "item2",20,2,
        "item3",30,3,
        "item4",40,4,
        "item1",50,5,
        "item2",60,6,
        "item3",70,7,
        "item4",80,8,
        "item3",90,9,
        "item4",100,10
    };
    int main(){
        int ibarcode[10];int qty[10];char b[10];int price[10];int ju[10];int tot[10];
        int j,i,k,grand;
        char a;
        printf("Cashier program\n");
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            printf("enter barcode : ");scanf("%d",&ibarcode[j]);
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                if(ibarcode[j]==detail[i].barcode){
                    printf("item name: %s\n",detail[i].name);
                    printf("price : %d\n",detail[i].price);
                    printf("Quantity : ");scanf("%d",&qty[j]);
                    tot[j]=detail[j].price*qty[j];
                }
               if(ibarcode[j] > 10){
                    printf("Barcode not valid\n");
                    j--;
                    break;
               }
            }
            printf("\nDo you want to buy again? [Y/N] = ");scanf("%s", &a);
            b[j] = detail[i].name;
            ju[j] = detail[i].price;
            if(a=='Y'||a=='y'){
               continue;
            } else {
               break;
            }
        }
        grand = 0; system("cls");
  printf("\n name Kasir = Addzifi Moch G\n");
  printf(" Tanggal    = 03 januari 2017\n");
  printf(" Jam        = 14:05 WIB\n\n");
  printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
  printf("| Barcode | name item\t\t\t| price \t\t| Quantity\t| Total   |\n");
  printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
 for(k=0; k<=j; k++){
  grand += tot[k];
  printf("|    %d \t  | %s\t                | %d\t\t       | %d\t\t\t| %d |\n", ibarcode[k], b[k], ju[k], qty[k], tot[k]);
 }
 printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
 printf("|\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  Total Yang Harus Dibayarkan  =  %d |\n", grand);
 printf("+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
}
```

Comment: `char` and `char*` (pointer) are different things. You probably need to de-reference a pointer somewhere using `&`.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson wouldn't using the ampersand operator evaluate to of type of `char**` , and not `char` ?

Comment: You should show us which line the error occurs on.   (The error message comes with a line number).  Otherwise, we're only guessing.

Comment: the error message is on `b[j] = detail[i].name;`

Comment: @George Yeah, I think I've had a bit too much christmas cheer today. I meant to say "de-reference the pointer using `*`".

Comment: I think OP needs `char b[10][MAX_NAME_SIZE]` and to copy the string with `strcpy(b[j], detail[i].name);`.

Answer (score 5):

I bet that happens on the line

```
b[j] = detail[i].name;
```

and that is because `b` is an array of characters and `name` is a string, so you want to assign to `b[j]`, a char, a string.

use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(b, detail[i].name);
```

Comment: is there any way which is not using `strcpy`?

Comment: Yes: declare `b` as an array of pointers to chars, i.e. `char *b[10];` Now your `b[j] = detail[i].name;` will be valid.

Comment: worked for me, with a bonus: cleaned up original car array,which had non ascii characters because of `strcat`, applied to populate it.